# I can't find table in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm really new to this stuff so this might be stupid. But I can't seem to figure out why this very basic line of code can't find any tables... Also trying to find a table to get each row basically.
The url : https://uwflow.com/course/cs136

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://uwflow.com/course/cs136"

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    enter code here

table = page_soup.findAll('table')
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored inside the page inside `<script>` tag. If you want solution without `selenium` you can use `re` and `json` modules to parse the data out.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://uwflow.com/course/cs136'

txt = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads(re.findall(r'window.pageData.courseObj = (\{.*?});', txt)[0])

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment this to see all data

print(data['code'] + ' - ' + data['name'])
print(data['description'])

print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format('Class', 'Enrolled', 'Campus'))
for section in data['sections']:
    print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(section['class_num'],
        str(section['enrollment_total']) + '/' + str(section['enrollment_capacity']),
        section['campus']))
```

Prints:

```
CS 136 - Elementary Algorithm Design and Data Abstraction
This course builds on the techniques and patterns learned in CS 135 while making the transition to use an imperative language. It introduces the design and analysis of algorithms, the management of information, and the programming mechanisms and methodologies required in implementations. Topics discussed include iterative and recursive sorting algorithms; lists, stacks, queues, trees, and their application; abstract data types and their implementations.
Class      Enrolled   Campus    
6214       90/90      UW U      
6011       59/65      UW U      
5914       46/90      UW U      
6004       90/90      UW U      
6048       90/90      UW U      
6109       90/90      UW U      
6215       87/90      UW U      
6260       90/90      UW U      
6261       67/90      UW U      
6005       64/65      UW U      

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you! And for future reference, how do I know whether it's enclosed in a script tag or not? Because when I did inspect element and saw the html, there was just body, a couple divs and then the table

Comment: @MostafizurRahman When I clicked to `View source` in Firefox and searched for string, e.g. class `5914` then only match there was inside `<script>` tag, along other data.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://uwflow.com/course/cs136")

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/68fb25b4fe45d52f5ac064228a64d32c/out.csv)

> I've taken `Winter 2020`, In case if you want `Spring 2020` so you need to change `[0]` to `[1]`

Comment: Tbh I was asking more to figure out why it wasn't a working with beautiful soup, not an alternative

Comment: Page is rendered via JavaScript so that’s why I’ve used selenium